# Do my blog page views help my main site's page ranking, if they are on the same domain?

Tags: seo

My company has a blog, that we release weekly articles on. A few have gotten moderate traffic (more than our actual site's home page). I am trying to figure out if the effort we spend on writing these articles is helping our main site's page ranking. Our site is company.com and our blog is company.com/blog.

I know any traffic is good, but our main goal is to increase our home page's page rank for searches that are not related to blog articles. For example, we have a blog article about using social engagement in mobile apps, that is near the top when those keywords are searched. Does this help our page rank when people search for mobile development consulting companies (which is what we actually do)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this question recently on:

[Do all the pages on a website help the homepage's SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67420/do-all-the-pages-on-a-website-help-the-homepages-seo/67421#67421)

I think this will answer your question, however, each scenario is a bit different of course.

If this is not enough or you have additional questions, please leave a comment and I will update the answer.

Comment: Whenever you see a question is essentially a duplicate flag it as such so it can be closed accordingly. :)

Comment: @John Conde Do I use flag for this? I did look at close, but did not see an option. Perhaps I should have checked flag.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for the link. It was extremely helpful.

Comment: Anytime! I like to help people which is why I am here. I am glad you liked the original answer. Thank you!

Comment: @closetnoc Yes. The is a small "flag" link underneath the question. It will be one of the options.

Comment: @John Conde Thanks! I have used flag before for spam, but I really should have dug further on this one. Now I know how to mark a question as duplicate and will in the future. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: @closetnoc No worries. As your rep increases you get more power. With great power comes great responsibilities! :)